# Make S3 Object public when uploaded by client-s3 Typescript library

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am uploading files to S3 using Typescript code as follows:

```
    import {PutObjectCommand, PutObjectCommandInput, S3Client} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
    const s3 = new S3Client(config);
    const uploadParams: PutObjectCommandInput = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: filename,
        Body: fileData
    };
 
    await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
```

However, I need to make object public after uploading in order to access it as a part of a static website and it is uploaded as private. How I can tell the s3 client to also make it public?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `uploadParams`, you can supply parameters described in [PutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/modules/putobjectrequest.html), including `ACL`.

Or, after upload, you can use [PutObjectAclCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/putobjectaclcommand.html) and the `public-read` canned ACL.

An alternative is to simply make all objects within the S3 bucket public via S3 bucket policy, so you don't have to make each and every object public individually. This assumes that all objects in the bucket are designed to be publicly readable, of course, as is often the case with static sites.

Comment: Thank you! In fact even simpler: uploadParams in my text can be amended as `{... Body: fileData, ACL:'public-read'`}.

Comment: Good find. The new SDK docs are a little tricky to navigate. I've added that info to my answer.

Comment: I found that on the current (3.504) version of `aws-sdk` (not sure how far back this goes), the ACL parameter is now typed — so you can't just pass a string. To fix this,  import `ObjectCannedACL` and then specify the parameter as `ACL: ObjectCannedACL.public_read`.